# JEE 7 CMT Transactions with @Transactional and JPA EntityManager

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions, entitymanager, transactional

If I use the @Transactional annotation for a service session method, do I still need to use the begin(), commit() and rollback() methods of the Transaction object accessed via the JPA EntityManager.  If so, what is the value that the @Transactional annotation provides if it doesn't automatically demarcate the transaction boundaries to begin and commit transactions?
Is the code for the transactional method below well formed or is there something that should be changed?

For example:

```
public class MyDataSession {

  @PersistenceContext( unitName = "default" )
  EntityManager myEntityManager;
  protected EntityManager getEntityManager() { return myEntityManager; }
  ...

@Transactional public void storeMyData( MyData inMyData )
{
  try {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    getDataService().storeMyData( inMyData  );
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
  }
  catch( Exception errorException )
  {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you should not. It will throw an IllegalStateException if you do in a Java EE context, which uses a JTA transaction manager. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getTransaction--. So your method body should thus be `getDataService().storeMyData(inMyData);`

Comment: JB, thanks.  I did get the IllegalStateException as you indicated would happen.  I am actually trying to resolve a data refresh issue in the UI that is too complex to detail here and thought might be related to the CMT and persistence of the data that is not getting refreshed after data updates using CMT.